Two's Complement Operator Qiskit Circuit Library
What is the practical method to convert current binary value into its two's complement version.
For example:
$\sim|0110\rangle = |1010\rangle$
Can I use CDKMRippleCarryAdder for such purpose? Or is there already existing module?

Notice that if you are focused on arithmetic circuits, you might prefer classiq, that handles the variable arithemtic in the design and execution. See this example https://docs.classiq.io/latest/classiq_101/classiq_concepts/design/. It handles the qubit mapping behind the scenes so you can code arithmetic like regular python

An alternative approach to the one proposed by @tristan-nemoz can be implemented by noticing that the two's complement of a binary number can also be obtained by inverting all the bits to the left of the first encountered 1 (going from LSB to MSB), and leaving all the other bits unchanged.
For instance, Take the binary number 1011000, whose two's complement is 0101000. Notice how the 4 least significant bits are left unchanged (1000) and the three most significant bits were flipped (from 101 to 010).
So, to implement this with a quantum circuit, all we need to do is create a series of controlled gates that flip only the qubits after the first 1 is encountered.
Here's the code to implement a quantum circuit to find the two's complement for a number using this approach:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector

state = '1011000' # state to be converted to two's complement
n = len(state)    # number of qubits

# Create gate that flips n qubits
def invert_box(n):
    qc = QuantumCircuit(n, name=' X_box')
    qc.x(range(n))
    return qc.to_gate()

qc = QuantumCircuit(n)
qc.prepare_state(state)
for i in range(1,n):
    qc.append(invert_box(n-i).control(i,ctrl_state='1'+'0'*(i-1)),range(n))

print(Statevector(qc).sample_memory(1)[0])

The code above generates the following circuit:

The $X$ gates at the beginning just initialize the state, and the controlled X_box blocks simply flip the most significant qubits after the first 1 is encountered.
If you run this code, you will see the output will print 0101000 which is the correct two's complement of the input.

The two's complement is given by flipping all the bits and adding $1$. The only complicated part is the latter, but we can do it using the QFT, in a similar fashion to DraperQFTAdder. We start from a basis state $|x\rangle$, and we apply the QFT on it:
$$F|x\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum_y\mathrm{e}^{\frac{2\mathrm{i}\pi xy}{2^n}}\,|y\rangle\,.$$
Writing $|y\rangle$ as $\left|b_{n-1},\cdots,b_0\right\rangle$, we then apply $P\left(\frac{2^{1+k}\pi}{2^n}\right)$ on $b_k$, which performs the following mapping:
$$|y\rangle\mapsto\mathrm{e}^{\frac{2\mathrm{i}\pi y}{2^n}}\,|y\rangle\,.$$
Applying this on our state yields:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum_y\mathrm{e}^{\frac{2\mathrm{i}\pi xy}{2^n}}\mathrm{e}^{\frac{2\mathrm{i}\pi y}{2^n}}\,|y\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum_y\mathrm{e}^{\frac{2\mathrm{i}\pi (x+1)y}{2^n}}\,|y\rangle=F|x+1\rangle\,.$$
We can then apply the inverse QFT to recover $|x+1\rangle$. All in all, this gives the following code:
def two_complement_gate(n_qubits):
    N = 1 << (n_qubits - 1)
    
    qc = QuantumCircuit(n_qubits)
    qc.x(range(n_qubits))
    qc.append(QFT(n_qubits), range(n_qubits))
    
    for i in range(n_qubits):
        qc.p(pow(2, i) * pi / N, i)
    
    qc.append(QFT(n_qubits, inverse=True), range(n_qubits))
    
    return qc

We can be a little more clever and remove the SWAPS in the QFT if we reverse the order of the phase gates, which gives the following code:
def two_complement_gate(n_qubits):
    N = 1 << (n_qubits - 1)
    
    qc = QuantumCircuit(n_qubits)
    qc.x(range(n_qubits))
    qc.append(QFT(n_qubits, do_swaps=False), range(n_qubits))
    
    for i in range(n_qubits):
        qc.p(pow(2, i) * pi / N, n_qubits - i - 1)
    
    qc.append(QFT(n_qubits, inverse=True, do_swaps=False), range(n_qubits))
    
    return qc

You can then append this gate to your circuit using the append method of QuantumCircuit. For instance, the following code:
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
from qiskit.primitives import StatevectorSampler

qc = QuantumCircuit(4)
qc.initialize(Statevector.from_label("0110"))
qc.append(two_complement_gate(4), range(4))
qc.measure_all()

sampler = StatevectorSampler()
sampler.run([(qc)]).result()[0].data.meas.get_counts()

returns {'1010': 1024}.
Of course, instead of having a custom incrementer like this, you could use pre-built ones, but I'm not sure there exists such in Qiskit that don't use ancilla qubits.
